# Marker requires clicking twice to keep InfoWindow open

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I have a map application that uses Android Google Maps API V2, although, when the user clicks on any Marker, the InfoWindow appears for a second and becomes invisible right after. If the user clicks again, the InfoWindow is displayed without problem this time.

I'm extending the SupportMapFragment using the code from the link below and creating a fragment that extends the SherlockMapFragment class.

https://gist.github.com/galex/4392030

The fragment class overrides the onMarkerClick method and returns false, indicating that the application has not handled the event "manually".

Can you help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem found. It was a logic error causing the marker to be removed and close the InfoWindow.

Sorry, my mistake.